# Map an dynamic array in array js

Tags: javascript, arrays, web, frontend, web-frontend

I have an array(it isn't final version, the array is dynamic)

```
[{
      "TemplateName": "C__01",
      "Template": "<div><h1>Hello world!</h1><div id='C__01__body'></div></div>",
      "TemplateBody": "body",
      "TemplateChildren": [{
        "TemplateName": "C__02",
        "Template": "<p>Hello1</p>",
        "TemplateBody": null,
        "TemplateChildren": [{
          "TemplateName": "C__03",
          "Template": "<p>Hello2</p>",
          "TemplateBody": null,
          "TemplateChildren": [{
            "TemplateName": "C__04",
            "Template": "<p>Hello3</p>",
            "TemplateBody": null,
            "TemplateChildren": null
          }, {
            "TemplateName": "C__05",
            "Template": "<p>Hello4</p>",
            "TemplateBody": null,
            "TemplateChildren": null
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }];
```

I'm not looking for a field, I just need to map each array in array

Comment: What do you mean by map each array in array? What approach did you choose?

Comment: I want to do something like that ```array.map()``` for each array in array

Comment: Can you provide the sample output you need?

Comment: Hello. I don't need an output. I need to change ```innerHTML``` to use the fields value from the array. Because i neccesary to do ```array.map()``` for each array in array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const parse = arr => {
      arr.map(item => {
        console.log(item);
        if (item.TemplateChildren) {
          parse(item.TemplateChildren);
        } else {
          return [];
        }
      });
    }
```